# Get outlook organisation team hierarchy using vba

Tags: vba, excel, properties, outlook

I have a list of staff emails in an Excel sheet and I'm trying to retrieve users' organisational team hierarchy using VBA. The output I am after is like the following:

**Email address, Team Hierarchy**

**aaa@email.com, Team 1\Team 2\Team 3\Team 4**

**bbb@email.com,  Team 1\Team 5\Team 6\Team 7**

I've seen that team hierarchy information is readily shown in Outlook (right-click contact -> Properties -> General tab -> Organisation field). So I think there should be a way to retrieve this information to a spreadsheet using VBA, but couldn't find a way to do it.

I did some research and saw that using LDAP there are ways to get the basic information directly from Active Directory such as First name, Last name, Org unit (team), etc., but couldn't find a way to get the team hierarchical view.

Appreciate if someone can help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use ExchangeUser.GetDirectReports and GetExchangeUserManager methods.

ExchangeUser can be retrieved from AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dmitry.

Comment: I tried to use the ExchangeUser method, but I found it difficult because I'm dealing with more than 100k contacts and it takes ages to iterate and find the relevant one using the email address (primary smtp address property).  Unfortunately, the AddressEntries collection can be queried only using the name, NOT the email address.    Luckily I was able to resolve this after following one of your older replies to [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918536/find-exchange-user-via-primary-smtp-address). Thanks!